# Not able to get the "id" value in Fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I am not getting the values when I click on the appointment.
I always receive "Undefined"

I have this codepen https://codepen.io/egameiro/pen/Rwbgemx where you can see the results.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong..?
Many thanks.

See below my code.

```js
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
  plugins: ['interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid'],
  defaultView: 'dayGridMonth',

  locale: 'pt-br',
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
  },
  navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
  selectable: true,
  selectHelper: true,
  //selectMirror: true,
  editable: true,
  eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events

  //events: event1,
  events: [{
    id: '10',
    title: 'Meeting',
    start: '2019-08-01T10:30:00',
    end: '2019-08-01T12:30:00'
  }],

  eventClick: function (event) {
    alert(event.id);
    alert(event.title);
    alert(event.start.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss'));
    return false;
  },



});

calendar.render();
```

Comment: Your js code should run after html rendered completely

Comment: @JaydipJadhav that's got nothing to do with this specific issue. `eventClick` executes in response to a user click, so the HTML will definitely be rendered by that time. See the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57724147/5947043) to understand the real problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation for eventClick](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventClick) the object provided by the callback is not simply a copy of the event data by itself. It's a more complex object, 
of which the event is just one sub-property. The documentation says:

> `eventClickInfo` is a plain object with the following properties:
>
> - `event`  The associated Event Object.
> - `el`     The HTML element for this event.
> - `jsEvent`    The native JavaScript event with low-level information such
>     as click coordinates.
> - `view`   The current View Object.

Therefore the event's data such as `id`, `title` etc will be properties within that `event` sub-property, not direct children of the main object.

Once you have read that and understood the structure of the object properly, the fix is trivial:

```
eventClick: function (info) {
    alert(info.event.id);
    alert(info.event.title);
    alert(info.event.start.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss'));
    return false;
  },
```

Updated CodePen: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/XWraJQx

P.S. You will still have a secondary problem here because `info.event.start` is a native JS Date object, not a momentJS object. Therefore it does not have any function called "format()". Perhaps you are more familiar with fullCalendar version 3 where momentJS was used? I will leave it to you to decide how you want to deal with this specific detail, as it's not directly relevant to your original question.